# How can I use two datasources in a CFQUERY?

Tags: sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am using ColdFusion 9.1.

I need to use two different datasources in some of my queries.  I know it can be done because I see other code that uses two different datasources and it works fine.

I've tried lots of combinations but can't get anything to work, but I know that both of my datasources are working properly.

I have a default database set up in the THIS scope.  The default is "DatasourceOne".

```
<cfquery>
SELECT UserID
FROM   DatasourceOne.TableOne IN (SELECT Userid FROM DatasourceTwo.TableTwo )
</cfquery
```

What are the rules or guidelines about using multiple datasources?

CLARIFICATION

I should have originally asked how I could use two database (not datasources) in a single query. I am sure your answers would have been different. We do have both databases set up as datasources though and I was a little confused myself.

Comment: What code have you seen where this works? It seems very strange.

Comment: I agree!!! I have never seen it used outside of the project that I am doing now. I am modifying some old code and putting it into a new site. But the query is being put into a CFC and isn't working.

Comment: I think you are best off using two queries here. I've never seen two datasources work in the same query. Which doesn't mean it can't have worked at some point ;) but still future developers will thank you for making it two queries!

Comment: @Sam, I am one of those "future developers" that would be grateful if someone had taken your advice.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Depending on your database, if the second database is on the same server (or is defined as a linked server) and the user in the datasource has permission, you can usually reference the other database.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE myField IN 
(SELECT otherField FROM otherDatabase.dbo.tableName)
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer and explanation!

Comment: This syntax "otherDatabase.dbo.tableName " is for MicroSoft SQL. Exclude the .dbo portion to get your query to execute in MySQL.

Answer (score 12):

You can't talk to two CF (JDBC) datasources in a single CFQUERY. What you can do:

- Use two databases on the same datasource. For example, if you have a SQL Server instance with two database you can run a query through the JDBC connection that talks to both databases. This looks like what you're describing in your question. [Here's a more thorough explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368351/how-many-datasources-can-coldfusion-handle/4368867#4368867).
- Use Queries of Queries. Pull your data from the two database individually and join the results using a QoQ in your CFC or page.

Comment: I agree with bpanulla.  Doing a query of queries is probably the easiest solution here.

Comment: Actually, the easier solution for us was to refer to the second database via its full path. Thanks for providing two solutions and explanations though.

Answer (score 7):

ColdFusion can only talk to one data*source* at a time in a given query.  However, if you need to talk to more than one data*base* on the same server, you can do that by explicitly giving the full paths to the databases, tables, and columns you need to access or join together.  Also note that the user that the data*source* in ColdFusion is configured to use must have access to both databases in order for this to work.